# sql - insert if not exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having trouble with a sql query.  I need to insert a row if the same row does not exist already.  This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
   FOR FOLDER_ROW IN (SELECT FOLDERID, USERID FROM DATA1.FOLDERS)
      LOOP                       
          IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DATA1.FOLDER_USER WHERE FOLDER_ID = FOLDER_ROW.FOLDERID AND USER_ID = FOLDER_ROW.USERID) 
          INSERT INTO DATA1.FOLDER_USER (FOLDER_ID, USER_ID) VALUES (FOLDER_ROW.FOLDERID, FOLDER_ROW.USERID);
     END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

I would not be very familiar with sql particularly the not exists syntax so when I execute I get the following error:

> ORA-06550: line 37, column 11: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "INSERT" when expecting one of the following:
>
> then and or

The symbol "then" was substituted for "INSERT" to continue.

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 38, column 10:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:
>
>    if
> ORA-06550: line 40, column 5:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
>
>    end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static
>    member constructor map
> ```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do it all in SQL rather than context switching into PL/SQL:

```
INSERT INTO DATA1.FOLDERS
(folder_id,
 user_id)
SELECT f1.folder_id,
       f1.user_id
  FROM DATA1.FOLDERS f1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM DATA1.FOLDERS f2
                    WHERE f1.folder_id = f2.folder_id
                      AND f1.user_id = f2.user_id);
```

Comment: ++1 `IF EXISTS()...INSERT` is usually not atomic, meaning a conflicting record could be inserted between the existence check and the insert.

Comment: @M_M - A SQL statement in Oracle is always atomic.  If there is no unique index, you may end up with conflicts because another session inserted didn't see the row because the first session hadn't committed it yet.

Comment: I can't speak to Oracle's behavior here, but will take your word for it. I know some DBMS treat `IF EXISTS(...) THEN` and `INSERT INTO` as two statements, not one, but it depends on transaction isolation levels and the like as well.

Answer (score 2):

A better (Oracle specific?) solution may be the MERGE statement.

See here for a nice explanation, with examples:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/MergeEnhancements10g.php

Hope that helps.

Comment: `MERGE` is not Oracle-specific.  It is actually part of `SQL:2008`.  For example, [DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html) (at least since v9 for z/OS, and 9.5 for LUW) and [SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), since 2008.

Comment: Thanks galador, I'm pretty much exclusively an Oracle guy, so I wasn't sure if MERGE was SQL standard or Oracle extension.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the **THEN**

```
IF condition THEN  
   ...
ELSE
    ...
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
    N_COUNTS NUMBER;
BEGIN
    select count(ID) into N_COUNTS from TABLE_NAME where ID = 1;
    IF N_COUNTS=0 THEN
        INSERT QUERY....
    ELSE
        UPDATE QUERY....
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Needed Similar for Sqlite**

I need to insert into a sqlite db but only if the key doesn't already exist.

id is the primary key autoincremented.
key is a unique string.

**MainToken Table**

```
id |  key   |   created    | active
 1 | test   |   2022-01-07 |  1
 2 | 2ndOne |   2021-12-19 |  1
```

Finally, if the item already exists then I want that id but if it was just inserted then I want that new id.

**Query That Works -- based on answer**

```
insert into maintoken (key)  
      select $key 
       where not exists 
       (select key from maintoken where key=$key);
       select id from maintoken where key=$key and active=1;
```

1. This will insert the $key value into the maintoken table
   only if the $key doesn't already exist.
2. After the new unique key is inserted it will select and get the new ID value and return it.
3. If the new key isn't unique it will return the value of that existing key's id.