# if select then insert in SQL

Tags: mysql

**I would like to only insert a row, if the following SELECT returns a 0 or no rows.**

Something like:

**IF ( SELECT IS 0) THEN INSERT()**

how can I do this in MYSQL ?

I just want to do one query instead of this two queries:

```
 $r=mysql_query("SELECT `ID`,`Country` FROM `Users` WHERE `IP`='".$ip."'",$connection);

 if(!$r || mysql_num_rows($r) <= 0)
     $ir=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Users` (`IP`,`Country`) VALUES ('".$ip."','".$country."')",$connection);
```

Comment: Do you want to ensure some column(s) uniqueness? If so, then use `UNIQUE` / `PRIMARY` key and `INSERT IGNORE` statement

Comment: in Oracle it is MERGE, not sure if that is supported in mysql.

Comment: Looking for [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)?

Comment: No, I'm looking to insert a row if I cannot find this row in database...

Comment: Use a primary key as poncha suggests.

Comment: @user1267305 Which is what that syntax will do. If there will be a key duplicate you can just set `id = id` for the update. It's not clear what you want to do. Post some SQL statements so we can all talk code, which is what we do understand better.

Comment: I just saw your code. Why not add a `UNIQUE` constraint for `Country` & `IP`. Then when there is a duplicate you just update `ID = ID`?

Comment: maybe you right...can you show me code with using UNIQUE, I'm new to sql and not sure...and If I see code then I can understand better and test

Comment: To add the `UNIQUE` constraint you would do `ALTER TABLE \`Users\` ADD UNIQUE (\`Country\`,\`IP\`);`. Then the query would be `INSERT INTO \`Users\`(\`Country\`, \`IP\`) VALUES('US','23.123.123') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE \`ID\` = \`ID\`;`

Comment: can you also advice how to remove duplicate rows from my database, I have many rows with same IPs and it cannot create unique.

Comment: How about you create a new table, and then insert everything from the old table to the new one with the above method? I wouldn't advice this if the table is big though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what he may be looking for is something along the lines of this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8185348

EDIT:
Also incase you ever have problems where you need to remove uniqueness or other constraints:

```
show create table <tablename>
```

This will show u all the details of the created table..

then you have to drop via the reference that it has
Ex:

```
UNIQUE KEY <reference_name> (‘value’)
```

so then you do:

```
alter table <tablename> drop index <reference_name>
```

Comment: That's a whole lot of complexities and inner queries. When `INSERT INTO \`Users\`(\`Country\`, \`IP\`) VALUES('US','23.123.123') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE \`ID\` = \`ID\`;` would suffice, if there was a `UNIQUE` constraint on *`(\`Country\`, \`IP\`)`*

Comment: I think you are right, how to add UNIQUE to already created table to some columns ?

Comment: @user1267305 I just gave you the query in the comments of the question.

Comment: can you also advice how to remove duplicate rows from my database, I have many rows with same IPs and it cannot create unique..

Comment: Just choose 1 
then
DELETE FROM `Users` WHERE ID != '1234' AND IP='123.123.123'

Or something to this extent..

Comment: I tried this:

DELETE Users WHERE `Users`.`IP` IN (SELECT `IP` FROM `Users` GROUP BY `IP` HAVING COUNT(IP) > 1);

but sintax is with errors, why?

Comment: Because it's `DELETE FROM Users ...`, but be _careful_ with that query. It will delete _all_ records which have duplicates, and you will be left with nothing.

Comment: I tried this : DELETE FROM Users WHERE IP NOT IN
(SELECT IP 
     FROM Users 
     GROUP BY IP 
     HAVING COUNT(IP) > 1) 
 
and got this: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'Users' for update in FROM clause

Comment: You can use `DELETE FROM Users WHERE IP NOT IN (SELECT * FROM(SELECT IP FROM Users GROUP BY IP HAVING COUNT(IP) > 1) ip_rows)`, but again, be careful.

Answer (score 0):

True, insert

```
IF(SELECT 1, INSERT INTO users, 0)=1
```

False, don't insert

```
IF(SELECT 0, INSERT INTO users, 0)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add unique key (if it is still not there)

   `ALTER TABLE Users ADD UNIQUE KEY (IP);`
2. whenever you get new ip/country pair do this:

   `INSERT IGNORE INTO Users (IP,Country) VALUES ('1.2.3.4','Zimbabwe');`

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO users (IP,Country)
VALUES ( xx, yy)
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
   FROM users nx
   WHERE nx.ip = xx -- KEYFIELDS
   );
```